# Ubuntu would not boot after Upgrade to 18.04

Tags: 16.04, boot, upgrade, 18.04

I upgraded my Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 yesterday night but it not booting now. It gives the following error message.

Could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin':-2
aux_get_response timeout, switching to single_cmd mode : last cmd=0x201f0500

I understand some people are having similar problems but mine is peculiar in the sense that, I cannot even boot.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the easiest way to resolve the issue but from my experience the fastest and easiest. Instead of an upgrade install newer version of Ubuntu from scratch.
After it's done restore your personal files and config from backup (it's usually mostly your user's home directory) and install all the tools you use (I keep a list in a txt file - if a list is long enough you may consider having a script for future use).